# Is it possible to view Mapillary sequences in parallel with Google Street View?

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, google-street-view, mapillary

Mapillary ([link](https://www.mapillary.com/)) provide streetview-like photos of many areas in the world.

The same is about Google Street View.

I'd like to show a parallel view on the same area about both images ... something like GeoFabrick Map Compare (rif http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/#15/49.0094/8.3902&num=4&mt0=mapnik&mt1=google-map&mt2=here-map&mt3=mapnik-german), to compare OpenStreetMap and others maps (Google Maps too ... ), but on images that when I move on the map could show what happen on Mapillary images and Google Street View images in parallel.

To clear my goal I'd like to have / build something like this ..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

but also with mapillary Images

Are there some tools or code samples in PHP / Javascript / Leaflet / OpenLayers?